# "Access to this API has been disallowed" while querying Financial Times'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, postman

How to get FT articles via their API ?

After asking for a key I first used [a python API wrapper](https://github.com/kaitlin/pyft) around their content API, v2. So I ran the following:

```
from pyft import FT

ft = FT()
# the id can be pulled from the slug url of an FT.com story
content = ft.get_content("6f2ca3d6-86f5-11e4-982e-00144feabdc0")
print(content)
```

And got:

```
{'error': 'Access to this API has been disallowed'}
```

So I followed [the official instructions](https://developer.ft.com/portal/docs-start-install-postman-and-import-request-collection) but got the same error :

[image]

Comment: Did you read the part about the key file in the docs and created it?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, it is the first thing I did. It is located in `C:\Users\me\.ft.key`

Answer (score 0):

This should be a Bug from FT. Since, the get_content_notifications without any issues.

```
notification = ft.get_content_notifications("2018-10-10T00:00:00.000Z")
print(notification)

{
"requestUrl": "https://api.ft.com/content/notifications?since=2018-10-10T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
"notifications": [
    {
        "type": "http://www.ft.com/thing/ThingChangeType/UPDATE",
        "id": "http://www.ft.com/thing/e75d5a6c-b725-11e8-bbc3-ccd7de085ffe",
        "apiUrl": "https://api.ft.com/content/e75d5a6c-b725-11e8-bbc3-ccd7de085ffe"
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm, I get `{'error': 'Access to this API has been disallowed'}
`

Comment: Because FT has blocked some access permission for their content API. Do you get the same error for get_content_notifications too?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately

Comment: Did you add the key properly? you have to just paste your access code to your `.ft.key` file

Answer (score 0):

This is because your API key is under Headline License, which only allows access to limited enpoints. Therefore, you should consider purchasing a [Datamining License](https://developer.ft.com/portal/docs-quick-start-guides-datamining-licence) in order to get access to more enpoints including the "get content" in your code. See more here: https://developer.ft.com/portal/docs-start-obtain-an-api-key

Answer (score 0):

Instructions from FT.com

- Download FT_API_Postman_Collection.json
- Open Postman
- Click Import, click Choose Files and specify FT_API_Postman_Collection.json. An import success message appears for each collection imported
- Click the Eye icon to setup an Environment
- Click Add
- Enter an Environment name. for example, FTAPI
- Copy your API Key from the email sent to you in the previous step
- Enter a Key and a Value
- Click Add
- Click Add

When you setup an FTAPI environment, make sure the variable is named 'KEY' as this is what it is called in the Postman collection.json